# MySQL sort a where in select

Tags: mysql

How would I sort a query like this in order to always have keywords from the q_and_a table on top followed by the sub_keywords from groups in alphabetical order?

```
SELECT * FROM q_and_a where 
          keyword = :keyword or 
          keyword in 
          (select distinct sub_keyword from groups 
                   where master_keyword = :keyword 
          order by sub_keyword) 
order by keyword
```

Comment: MySQL isn't really made for advanced formatting use cases. I use PHP and would have a main loop for the keyword then a subloop to extract all the sub_keywords for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a condition in order by to sort the direct matches first:

```
...
order by if(keyword=:keyword,1,0) desc
```

Comment: order by if(keyword=:keyword,1,0) desc, keyword